# Use 3rd party jQuery files in custom module Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, custom, third-party-plugin

**Trying to use slick slider in my custom module**

All css is loaded by `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/CompanyName/ReviewRating/view/frontend/layout/reviewrating_index_index.xml`

I am In Developer Mode.

I followed [Magento2 adding 3rd party jQuery files to module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76921/magento2-adding-3rd-party-jquery-files-to-module)

1) In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/CompanyName/ReviewRating/view/frontend/templates/reviewrating_index_index.phtml`

```
<section class="vertical-center slider">
    <div>
         <div class="dummy-content"> I am a Text </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="dummy-content"> I am a Text </div>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
     ".vertical-center" : {
        "customjs" : {
            "autoplaySpeed": 5000
        }
     }
}
</script>
```

2) In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/CompanyName/ReviewRating/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {

     map: {
        '*': {
            customjs: 'CompanyName_ReviewRating/js/customjs',
        }
    },
    paths:{
        "slick": "js/slick/slick"
    },
    shim:{
        'slick':{
            'deps':['jquery']
        }
    }
};

console.log('This is printed');
```

3) In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/CompanyName/ReviewRating/view/frontend/web/js/slick/`
    Below files are present in this location

```
 -> slick.js 
  ->slick.css
  ->slick-theme.css
```

Issue: js file is not loaded

> In console `GET http://localhost/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/js/slick/slick.js net::ERR_ABORTED`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing all of your code in action but here are a few suggestions I can think of that might help:

### Requirejs-config.js Formatting

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/CompanyName/ReviewRating/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`:

- Remove the comma after the `customjs: 'CompanyName_ReviewRating/js/customjs'` line. Javscript (JSON) doesn't allow trailing commas on arrays the same way PHP does.

### Clear Cache, Static Content, and Run Static Content Deploy

From your Magento root:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```