# Want to display the clock in logo

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.2.2, requirejs

I'm working for displaying the clock in the **logo**. it must display the current time.

I had modified `logo.phtml` and put the js for clock in `pub/static/fronend/theme/js` folder. All are went well.

And I had declare the **js** files on `app/design/front_end/theme/Magento_theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

while seeing the output al my js files are automatically merged in a single js file in dynamic so, my clock logo is failed to load and also an error in **required.js**

How can i avoid automatic merge of js files in dynamic ?

my js code is below,

```
var hands = [];
hands.push(document.querySelector('#secondhand > *'));
hands.push(document.querySelector('#minutehand > *'));
hands.push(document.querySelector('#hourhand > *'));

var cx = 100;
var cy = 100;

function shifter(val) {
 return [val, cx, cy].join(' ');
}

var date = new Date();
var hoursAngle = 360 * date.getHours() / 12 + date.getMinutes() / 2;
var minuteAngle = 360 * date.getMinutes() / 60;
var secAngle = 360 * date.getSeconds() / 60;

hands[0].setAttribute('from', shifter(secAngle));
hands[0].setAttribute('to', shifter(secAngle + 360));
hands[1].setAttribute('from', shifter(minuteAngle));
hands[1].setAttribute('to', shifter(minuteAngle + 360));
hands[2].setAttribute('from', shifter(hoursAngle));
hands[2].setAttribute('to', shifter(hoursAngle + 360));
```

Comment: anyone answer my question.. :{

Comment: In magneto, you can easily add any third party javascript, But you need to follow certain steps to add third-party javascript. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76921/magento2-adding-3rd-party-jquery-files-to-module
check this thread it might help you.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/custom-javascript-in-magento-2-with-requirejs/ another one good post which you can read-learn and implement to your module :)

Comment: Adding JS in other that `requirejs`, you will have many problems ! please post your code and what you did ?

Comment: @Prince i had added my js code.. i want to initialize this on startup of magento..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your js code in **theme** via `Requirejs` like this: `clockjs.js` = your clock js

**app/design/{Vendor}/{theme}/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            clock: 'Vendor_theme/js/clockjs'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js/clockjs.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function clock()
       {
           alert('hello clock);
           //put all your js clock code
       }
});
```

**app/code/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/{logofile}.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'clock'], function($, clock) {
        clock();
    });
</script>
```

**Info:** don't forget to :

- clean the cache
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content
- clean `pub/static` content
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: thank you..  it works.. i  need one clarification.. my store has a multi language views is it necessary to add manually  the js file to all lang folder in pub folder?

Comment: No, you don't need this, this is done automatically when you deploy the static contents. You're welcome